# How to transform the Laplacian from momentum space to coordinate space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, fourier-transform

I'm working through some quantum mechanics problems with solution sets (attempting the problems then looking at the solutions to compare), and a little part of a solution has stumped me. I'm not sure how the math works. How does one go from the Laplacian acting on a wave function described in momentum space to the result in coordinate space? Specifially, how does one achieve the result
$$\nabla^{2}\phi(p,t)\to -r^{2}\psi(r,t).$$

Comment: The same way you get *all* relations between momentum and position space: [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform).

Comment: $\uparrow$ Quantum mechanics problems from which reference?

Comment: The Problems and Solutions on Quantum Mechanics from the Major American Universities Ph.D. Qualifying Questions and Solutions series.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
Write the function $\phi(p,t)$ in terms of its Fourier components, i.e.:

$\phi(p,t) = \int dx \phi(x,t) e^{i p x}$

Step 2: Notice that the $\nabla$ operator acts now only on the exponential factor inside the integral. Doing the derivative results in:

$\int dx (-x^2) \phi(x,t) e^{i p x}$

Step 3: Multiply the equation by by a factor of $e^{-i p r}$ and integrate over the momentum $p$:
$\int dx \int dp (-x^2) \phi(x,t) e^{i p (x-r)} = \int dx (-x^2) \phi(x,t) \delta(x-r) = -r^2 \phi(r,t)$.

The last equality on the rhs is your result. I have used here a particular representation of the delta function: $\delta(x-r) = \int dp e^{i p (x-r)}$. Also above, I was sloppy with normalization factors of the Fourier transforms and delta functions. I'm sure you can fix them yourself when you work through it.

Edit: I also assumed here that your $\nabla$ operator is in fact the gradient in the momentum space, i.e. $\nabla = (\partial_{p_x}, \partial_{p_y}, \partial_{p_z})$,  because otherwise what you asked wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes. That is very useful. I knew to use the Fourier Transform, but I wasn't sure how to carry out the integrations. Thanks!